# copy cell value if adjacent cell is not empty

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a "Travel Expenses" sheet, where all expenses from different currencies are converted into USD via googlefinance. I need to copy that amount to a different cell to form a monthly report, so that if the currency rate changes significantly over the month, I have the right amount stored.

Basically if a cell in column U is not blank => copy it to adjacent cell in V.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iBIg8b4BuUyHiuvogePyRbOhQulp1rCtUMXHpN_YKuQ/edit#gid=1586216805

I'm using the following scipt for: 1) timestamps (works perfectly) 2) copying the currency (works, but is not what I need).

```
function onEdit(e)
{var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();                                             
   if (ss.getName() != "123")      // i use this for testing 

{
 var actRng = ss.getActiveRange();                                           
 var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();                                        
 var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();                                        
 var headers = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();         
 var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Date of expence") + 1;                    
 var orderCol = headers[0].indexOf("Name") + 1;

 if (dateCol > 0 && rowIndex > 1 && editColumn == orderCol)                  
 {
  ss.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+8", "dd-MM-yy"));}
 }

{
var source = ss.getRange ("U3:U400");
source.copyTo (ss.getRange ("V3:V400"), {contentsOnly: true});}
}
```

I suppose this should be done in 2 different scripts. This is my first experience with google scripts, so its very confusing for me)

Will accept all suggestions, thanks in advance!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
on Edit(e) {
  if(!e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,23).isBlank()) {
    e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,24).setValue(e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,23).getValue())
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!) This helped, and its nice seeing the rownumbers, I can modify them in case I create more columns.